# Checkbox not working inside ngTemplateOutlet when parent listens for click event - bug?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while now.

Basically, I have a `ng-template` that contains a single checkbox. I then include that into a component by using `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet>`. The `ng-container` is contained inside a `div` that has a click event listener. The listener does nothing currently, just an empty function.

When I run this, everything's good. I can check and uncheck the checkbox.

Here's the template code:

```
<div (click)="handleClick($event)">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="foo"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #foo>
  <input type="checkbox">
</ng-template>
```

If I add a `context` to the `ngTemplateOutlet`, though, this mysteriously breaks the checkbox. So, if I update the template code to this:

```
<div (click)="handleClick($event)">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="foo; context: context"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #foo>
  <input type="checkbox">
</ng-template>
```

and I have a property called `context` in my component class (just an empty object for now), the checkbox no longer gets checked when I click on it.

It would probably be easier just to link to the simple example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LHxdP3XBifuYbgmo3ptm

It's definitely the `context` that is causing this issue. When I remove the `context`, the checkbox works again.

EDIT: I forgot to mention - if I remove the `(click)` listener from the containing `div`, the checkbox works correctly as well. Could providing a `context` affect the propagation of events somehow?

Could this be an Angular bug? Or is there some concept I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is because you set empty context.

Comment: @Vega even if I add data to the context, I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the get accessor, like trackBy for *ngFor, context should be:

```
context() {
    return {};
}
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LKSVWLJXCAJf0y6qPUic?p=preview)

or declare context as a property:

```
context = {}
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/FS6683gm7rHo7w6eu51z?p=preview)